# How to prevent this distortion to a path curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms, path

Following a YouTube tutorial Easiest Way To Create Hair in Blender - 5 Minute Tutorial by YanSculpts, I get to 4:31 in the video where they grab a point however when I do this I get the following result see picture. The mesh appears to stretch in Z axis.

I have looked for a solution but I'm unable to ascertain what I need to change in order to remove this behaviour.

I'm using 3.5.1.
Thank you in advance.

[image: Curve Transform Result]